# How to precompute a const value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call environment variable based on a calculated value. Which means I can't use the `const String.fromEnvironment` constructor. However not using `const` results in a blank string.

Is there a way to precompute a const value in Flutter? This variables are defined by `--dart-define` so I can't use `Platform.environment`.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. Getting env vars have to be constant. I worked around by setting all my info as a json string, decoding it at runtime and set the keys as my computed values.